# "Class Not Found" running cod file compiled from j2me jar file

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have converted the jar files of a j2me app to COD files using rapc. When I run the cod file on the BlackBerry simulator, it says "Class Not Found" exception. Adding the jar file with the missing class to my project does not stop the exception from appearing.

What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Was this a BlackBerry app originally?

Comment: No it is a J2ME app basically,we want to port it to Blackberry.So i have converted the jar.jad files to cod file frm command prompt via RAPC command

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry's J2ME implementation is a subset of the standard J2ME. There are quite a few commonly used classes not included with it, so the problem is most likely that the app is using some of those.